# Class autoloading in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, autoload

Probably quite easy question, but I've just started working with ZF.

I have created a class `class Application_Paginator_Adapter_DoctrineQuery implements Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Interface` and I've added this class to a file `application/paginator/adapter/DoctrineQuery.php`. When I try to create object of that class inside controller I am getting error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Application_Paginator_Adapter_DoctrineQuery' not found.

I thought this class should be included automatically. How to do that?

I am using ZF 1.11 and MS Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DoctrineQuery.php should be in

/library/Application/Pagination/Adapter
rather than
/application/Pagination/Adapter

Comment: This assumes that the Application namespace has been registered

Comment: When using "dumb" autoloading it'S not assumed ;)

Comment: I am accepting this answer, because my problem was from the fact I didn't know, that I should put custom classes in library folder. If I understand this correctly, they should be there. So your answer helped me in understanding this.